# How to only execute partial codes of a method of super class in python?

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I know how to call the method of super class by using `super()`, like these:

```
>>> class A:
>>>     def func1(self):
>>>         print("1")
>>>         print("2")
>>>         print("3")

>>> class B(A):
>>>     def func1(self):
>>>         super().func1()
>>>         print("4")

>>> b = B()
>>> b.func1()
1
2
3
4
```

But now I would like to only execute partial codes of `A.func1()` in `b.func1()` and make the result looks like:

```
1
3
4
```

Are there any built-in function or site-package can help me to do that?

Comment: If you can give real code where this is gonna be useful then maybe you can get some good answer. You can split the function into even smaller functions. Or you can pass a boolean parameter with some default value that tell whether to execute some part in function or not. Answer really depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: You will need some logic in A.func1() to suppress *print("2")*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some code in A.func1() to suppress *print(2)*

```
class A:
    def func1(self):
        print(1)
        if type(self) is A:
            print(2)
        print(3)

class B(A):
    def func1(self):
        super().func1()
        print(4)

A().func1()
print()
B().func1()
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3

1
3
4
```